# Derivation of PCA - Unclear part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors, svd

In the derivation of PCA two steps look the following:

$\max E[ || U^T X_i ||_2^2 ] = \max_{||U_1||=1} E[ (U_1^T X_i)^2 ] = \max_{||U_1||=1} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (U_1^T X_i)(X_i^T U_1)$

Here, $U$ is an orthogonal matrix coming from SVD and $X_i$ is a column of the data matrix $X$.

I really wonder how the argumentation for removing the norm in the first step works, but also I can't wrap my head around the second step (shouldn't it be: $(U_1^T X_i)^2 = (U_1^TX_i)^T(U_1^TX_i)$)

I believe this is not a complicated reasoning but that I am missing out something obvious. So, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm trying to understand your misgivings with the seconds step. What's the difference between saying $(U_1^T X_i)^2 = (U_1^TX_i)^T(U_1^TX_i)$ and $(U_1^T X_i)^2 = (U_1^TX_i)(U_1^TX_i)^T$?